# UITextField's Clear Button set to 'Never Appears' but still shows when adding text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I need to never display the clear button on a specific text field.  in IB I've set the clear button as 'Never Appears'.  However, once the user inputs even 1 character into the text field, the clear button shows up.  These text fields are pretty short (due to spacing) and the clear button covers the written text, which looks terrible.

I need to do away with the clear button all together but setting it as 'Never Appears' still makes it appear.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in code, there may be a bug with IB. `self.myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;`

Comment: also check if you've made connection between textfield and uielement in IB

Comment: there is definitely a connection because text and everything appears fine, as well as the keyboard etc.  I'll try it programmatically and see what happens.

Comment: adding it programmatically had no change

Answer (score 3):

```
self.myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Should work to make it never appear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't set it to "Appears while editing" somewhere by mistake? 
The default value for the clearButtonMode property is UITextFieldViewModeNever.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) :

> **clearButtonMode**
>
> Controls when the standard clear button appears in the text field.
>
> `@property(nonatomic) UITextFieldViewMode clearButtonMode`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The standard clear button is displayed at the right side of the text
>   field as a way for the user to remove text quickly. This button
>   appears automatically based on the value set for this property.
>
> **The default value for this property is UITextFieldViewModeNever.**